# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' -php html and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a web app to buy sandwiches in the bar of our school. In the menu section when I click a sandwich it give me this problem:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' on Menu.php:2

Here is the code:

```
<?php
  include_once 'navbar.php';
  include_once '..\PHP\dbh-inc.php';
?>
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bar Giua</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Resources/CSS/stili.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <center>
  <!--Links tab-->
  <div>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'Cibo')">Cibo</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'Bevande')">Bevande</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'Caffetteria')">Caffetteria</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'Altro')">Altro</button>
  </div>
  <!--Contenuto tab-->
  <!--CIBO-->
  <div align="left" id="Cibo" class="tabcontent">
   <?php
      $qcibo = "SELECT Prodotti.Nome,Prodotti.Prezzo FROM Prodotti,CategorieProdotti WHERE Prodotti.Categorie = CategorieProdotti.id AND CategorieProdotti.Descrizione = 'panini';";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qcibo);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          echo "<button class='icone' onclick='openOrdine(event, 'Ordine')'></button>";
          //echo $row["Nome"].$row["Prezzo"]."<br>";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <!--BEVANDE-->
  <div align="left" id="Bevande" class="tabcontent">
 <?php
      $qbevande = "SELECT Prodotti.Nome,Prodotti.Prezzo FROM Prodotti,CategorieProdotti WHERE Prodotti.Categorie = CategorieProdotti.id AND CategorieProdotti.Descrizione = 'bevande';";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qbevande);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          echo "<input type='button' class='icone' onclick='openOrdine(event, 'Ordine')'>";
          //echo $row["Nome"].$row["Prezzo"]."<br>";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <!--CAFFETTERIA-->
  <div align="left" id="Caffetteria" class="tabcontent">
   <?php
      $qcafeteria = "SELECT Prodotti.Nome,Prodotti.Prezzo FROM Prodotti,CategorieProdotti WHERE Prodotti.Categorie = CategorieProdotti.id AND CategorieProdotti.Descrizione = 'Cafeteria';";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qcafeteria);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          echo "<input type='button' class='icone' onclick='openOrdine(event, 'Ordine')'>";
          //echo $row["Nome"].$row["Prezzo"]."<br>";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <!--ALTRO-->
  <div align="left" id="Altro" class="tabcontent">
   <?php
      $qaltro = "SELECT Prodotti.Nome,Prodotti.Prezzo FROM Prodotti,CategorieProdotti WHERE Prodotti.Categorie = CategorieProdotti.id AND CategorieProdotti.Descrizione = 'altro';";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qaltro);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          echo "<input type='button' class='icone' onclick='openOrdine(event, 'Ordine')'>";
          //echo $row["Nome"].$row["Prezzo"]."<br>";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </div>


   <div style="height: 100px" align="left" id="Ordine" class="tabcontent0">

    <h2 class="classep"></h2>
    <div class="inner">
     <div class="button">
    <input type="button" class="tasti" value="-" onclick="ordineMeno()">
    <input type="text"   class="textbox" value="1" id="numeroOrdine">
    <input type="button" class="tasti" value="+" onclick="ordinePiu()"> 
    <input type="checkbox" style="width:15px; height: 15px;" id="infarinato" name="Infarinato">
 <a style="font-size: 20px;"> Infarinato </a>

 </div>
     <input type="button" class="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addOrdine()">
  </div>
</div>


</center>
<form method="post" action="/carrello.php">
  <textarea  id="hide"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">
</form>
</body>
<script>
  function ordinePiu(){
    var numOrd = document.getElementById('numeroOrdine').value;
    numOrd = parseInt(numOrd);
    numeroOrdine.value = numOrd + 1;
  }

  function ordineMeno(){
    var numOrd = document.getElementById('numeroOrdine').value;
    numOrd = parseInt(numOrd);
    if(numOrd > 0){
      numeroOrdine.value = numOrd - 1;
    }
  }

  function openMenu(evt, menu){

    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");   

    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(menu).style.display = "block";

    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

  }

  function openOrdine(evt0, menu0){

  var i0, tabcontent0, tablinks0;

  tabcontent0 = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent0");

  for (i0 = 0; i0 < tabcontent0.length; i0++) {
        tabcontent0[i0].style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById(menu0).style.display = "block";

    evt0.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }

  function addOrdine(){
    Test
  }

</script> 
</html>
```

This is the included PHP: 

dbh-inc.php

```
<?php

$dbServerName = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "barettodb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Connessione fallita: " . die (mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

navbar.php

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bar Giua</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--BOOTSTRAP-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--NOSTRI FILE-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\Resources\CSS\TendinaDefault.css" type="text/css" /> 

  <style>

  body {
      font-size: 28px;
      background-color: #868686;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <!--<div id="login_bar" style="text-align: right">                                               
            <ul id="login_signup">
                <li><a href="#" id="login_link">Login <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="sign_link">SignUp <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>-->



  <!-- Menu --><!--
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn2 btn-primary dropdown-toggle position-sticky" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>  
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href=".\Home.php">Homepage</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Sezione Ristorazione</li>
      <li><a href="Menu.php"> Men&ugrave </a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Sezione Utente</li>
      <?php
      //Controllo se utente è loggato
      /*
      if(isset($_SESSION['user_ID'])) 
      {
        echo "<li><a href='./Profilo.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Modifica Password</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='../PHP/logout.inc.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-out'></span> Log Out</a></li>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<li><a href='./registrazione.php'> Registrazione</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='./Login.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> Log In</a></li>";
      }*/
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

-->
  <!--Logo del sito cliccabile -->
  <ul class="ultenda">
    <div style="float: center;">
      <center>
        <a href="Home.php"><img class="logoimg" src="..\Resources\Images\logo.png" alt="logo! :)"/></a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </ul>


  <style>
    #login_bar{
width:300px;        
position:fixed;
z-index: 10;
border:1px solid black;   
top:-5px;
right:0px;
}

#header{
width:1000px;    
background-image:url('../images/hf1.jpg'); 
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
border-radius:5px;
min-height: 100px;
}

#login_signup{
float:right;    
}

#login_signup > li{
float:left;    
padding-right: 30px;
list-style: none;
line-height:25px;
padding-top:6px;
display:inline-block;           
}

#login_signup li > a{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
color:white;
padding:5px;
display:inlineblock;
background-color:black;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;

box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-o-box-shadow:rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
}

#login_signup li span{  
font-size: 12px;        
display:inlineblock;
}

#login_signup li a:hover{
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
-o-box-shadow:rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: white;    
color:#006666;
}
  </style>

  <!-- Piè di pagina/Varie info -->
  <ul class="ultenda1">
    <div style="float: center;">
      <p style="color:red;" align="center">INFO</p>
    </div>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ..." is a JavaScript error.   Your last function just says "Test" inside it.

Comment: Its saying SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' on Menu.php:2  ..but i guess you have not attached this one . can you please attach this one may be we can sort out this

Comment: @TaylorRahul  I'm guessing the URL is "Menu.php" because it's a Sandwich menu.

Comment: Can you attach a screen ?

Answer (score 3):

I put my bet on this :

```
function addOrdine(){
    Test
}
```

Put proper code there, or comment your line

Comment: It's definitely this.  This is the submit button's click handler.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski this could be an issue but this is not what he is asking .. for this case it will not say SyntaxError .. it wll be something like undefined etc etc

Comment: it will be Test is not defined

Comment: Indeed it would.

Comment: I got this problem even before writing this test, anyway i got the problem when i click the openOrdine function :/